# Vue Router Auth Guard url Extra Charcters

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue route Auth Guard with before Each function. If a user is not logged in he can not be able to access dashboard and profile page. It is working fine but when I am trying route forcefully its blocking me but also adding some extra characters in the url. Can I be able to remove those.

url -    http://localhost:8080/?redirect=%2Fdashboard

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import * as firebase from "firebase";

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes : [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: () => import('../components/home')
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'signin',
      component: () => import('../components/user/signIn')
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'signup',
      component: () => import('../components/user/signUp')
    },
    {
      path: '/forgot-password',
      name: 'forgotPassword',
      component: () => import('../components/user/forgotPassword')
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'profile',
      component: () => import('../components/user/profile'),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: () => import('../components/dashboard'),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },

  ]
})

//Router Guard
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Check fore required auth guard
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)){
    // check if not logged in
    if(!firebase.auth().currentUser){
      // go to login
      next({
        path: '/',
        query: {
          redirect: to.fullPath
        }
      });
    }else{
      // proceed to route
      next();
    }
  }else{
    next();
  }
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user is not logged in, the router guard is redirecting to `path: '/', query: {redirect: to.fullPath}`.  At this point `to.fullPath == "/dashboard"`.

The forwardslash `'/'` character is not a valid query character, so vue-router converts this to the encoded version `%2F` using `encodeURIComponent("/dashboard")`.

When the user logs in, you can get the redirect parameter from `$route.query.redirect` and it will be automatically decoded back into `/dashboard`.

Alternatively, since all of your routes have names, instead of setting the `redirect` parameter to `to.fullPath` you could use set it to `to.name`, then when the user logs in you can redirect to the route by name.

Comment: So i will do this -----------

query: {
          redirect: to.name
        }

Comment: Yes, try that.  Remember though, if you use the route's name then you will have to ensure all future routes have a name.